# ReactJS fire an event into component when my global socket listener fires through socket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, redux, react-component

I am using ReactJS and i have connected socket as in the different file as global function.
There is a message event listener of socket and fires when any new message comes from backend.

Now what i want is that, i want to fire an event into component when my message event listener fires as it is defined as a global function.

Can anyone have an idea, how we do ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've made few (custom) event dispatching examples for you here: https://codesandbox.io/s/13287npq03. (Events will log to the console - expand it on Console click [image])

Basics:

1. If you want to get fired event inside of any React Component, you have to add the event listener, the best practice is to add it inside of componentDidMount:

   `componentDidMount = () => {
       let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");
       element.addEventListener("eventname", this.eventListener);
     };`

Note that you must have that element inside of one of your Component render method. 
E.G. `render() { return <div id="idOfEventListener" /> }`

2. You must have method which will be triggered when event occurs. Instead of element.addEventListener("eventname", this.eventListener); you can also create inline function `element.addEventListener("eventname", e => console.log('event occured', e));`, otherwise you will have to create event listener method inside of your Component:

   `eventListener = e => {
       console.log("event occured in component", e, e.target);
     };`
3. Best practice is to clean up (remove event listener) on Component unmount:

   `componentWillUnmount = () => {
           let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");
           element.removeEventListener(
             "eventname",
             EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
             false
           );
         };`

Explanation of https://codesandbox.io/s/13287npq03:

> EventHelper.js

I've created the generic dispatchCustomEvent method inside of separated file so you can use it (and dispatch event) from any component. It accepts target (DOM element, e.g. document.getElementById('idOfEventListener')), event name (it must be the same name you are listening for, in above addEventListener I specified I'm listening "eventname" only) and details -> custom data you want to provide, object/string/number, whatever you need.

```
export default {
  dispatchCustomEvent: (target, name, details) => {
    if (target) {
      let event = new Event(name, {
        details: details,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
      });

      target.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
  }
};
```

For event listener above I would have to call `EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent(document.getElementById("idOfEventListener"), "eventname", {test: "whatever data you need"})`, and my listener would trigger this.eventListener method and console log event & event.target (that would be DOM element ).

> You can call EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent when your message event listener fire, or if you know what your message event looks like - you could just listen for that message event inside of the Component you need it. If message event is global, I suppose it is creating the event on the window or document - you would have to create the event listener on Component like this:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let element = window || document;

    element.addEventListener("messageEventName", this.eventListener);
  };

  eventListener = e => {
    console.log("event inside second child component:", e, e.target);
  };

  componentWillUnMount = () => {
    let element = window || document;
    element.removeEventListener(
      "messageEventName",
      EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
      false
    );
  };
```

Other Components:

> index.js

Main/Parent Component which has 2 child components FirstChildComponent and SecondChildComponent. I've created 2 buttons inside of the render - first button will fire event which FirstChildComponent is listening for, and the second button will fire event "eventname" which is listened by parent (index.js) and SecondChildComponent, and it will trigger both parent and second child event listeners. Note that instead of binding that event to window or document, I've created `<div id="idOfEventListener">` which is the wrapper of the entire application, and both SecondChildComponent and parent can use it as event listener target and get events that are targeted to it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import FirstChildComponent from "./FirstChildComponent";
import SecondChildComponent from "./SecondChildComponent";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import EventHelper from "./EventHelper";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");

    element.addEventListener("eventname", this.eventListener);
  };

  eventListener = e => {
    console.log("event in parent component", e, e.target);
  };

  componentWillUnMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");
    element.removeEventListener(
      "eventname",
      EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
      false
    );
  };

  fireEvent = () => {
    let additionalData = { loremIpsum: "dolor sit amet" };
    let target = document.getElementById("FirstChildEventListener");
    EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent(
      target,
      "firstChildEventName",
      additionalData
    );
  };

  fireMultipleListenedEvent = () => {
    console.log("fire multiple");
    let additionalData = { test: "blabla" };
    let target = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");
    EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent(target, "eventname", additionalData);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="idOfEventListener" className="App">
        <h1>Parent Component</h1>
        <div id="GettingEventInParentComponent">
          Box in parent component listening for event
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.fireEvent}>
          Test Button that will fire event which FirstComponent will receive
        </button>

        <FirstChildComponent />
        <SecondChildComponent />

        <hr />

        <button onClick={this.fireMultipleListenedEvent}>
          Test Button that will fire event which is listened inside of Second
          Child Component and parent component both
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

> FirstChildComponent

Listens for the event on target inside of FirstChildComponent render (`<p id="FirstChildEventListener">`), and that event is triggered inside of another component (parent, but it could be easily triggered from the SecondChildComponent, and listener would still get it):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EventHelper from "./EventHelper";

export default class FirstChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("FirstChildEventListener");

    element.addEventListener("firstChildEventName", this.eventListener);
  };

  eventListener = e => {
    console.log("event inside first child component:", e, e.target);
  };

  componentWillUnMount = () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("FirstChildEventListener");
    element.removeEventListener(
      "firstChildEventName",
      EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
      false
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>First Child Component</h1>
        <p id="FirstChildEventListener">
          This element is inside of FirstChildComponent, and it only listens
          when event will be dispatched
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

> SecondChildComponent.js

Listens for the event on (parent) DOM element, outside of its render.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EventHelper from "./EventHelper";

export default class FirstChildComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");

    element.addEventListener("eventname", this.eventListener);
  };

  eventListener = e => {
    console.log("event inside second child component:", e, e.target);
  };

  componentWillUnMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("idOfEventListener");
    element.removeEventListener(
      "eventname",
      EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
      false
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Second Child Component</h1>
        <span>Listening event on upper level</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm firing events from parent Component (on buttons click), but you can just fire event inside of message event listener, and then create the event listener for that exact event inside of the Components you need it.

---

> **EDIT**:

---

I've added GlobalFile.js to codesandbox with example of websocket:

```
import EventHelper from "./EventHelper";

// or just copy dispatchCustomEvent function
/*function dispatchCustomEvent (target, name, details) {
  if (target) {
    let event = new Event(name, {
      details: details,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
    });

    target.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}*/

let jsWebSocket = null;

function initSocket(user_id) {
  jsWebSocket = new WebSocket("wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo");
  jsWebSocket.addEventListener("open", function(event) {
    jsWebSocket.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
      console.log("message listener fired");
      let elementInsideOfComponent = document.getElementById(
        "elementInsideOfComponnet"
      );
      let someData = { id: "message1" };
      // if element target exists dispatch event to component
      console.log(elementInsideOfComponent);
      if (elementInsideOfComponent)
        EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent(
          elementInsideOfComponent,
          "websocketmessage",
          someData
        );
    });
  });
}

function sendMessage() {
  jsWebSocket.send("Here's some text that the server is urgently awaiting!");
}

export default { initSocket, sendMessage, jsWebSocket };
```

Added ComponentListeningForGlobalEvent.js with DOM element `<div id="elementInsideOfComponnet">Listening for global message</div>` which will be target of dispatched event from websocket message event:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EventHelper from "./EventHelper";

export default class ComponentListeningForGlobalEvent extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("elementInsideOfComponnet");

    element.addEventListener("websocketmessage", this.eventListener);
  };

  eventListener = e => {
    console.log("websocketmessage event inside component:", e, e.target);
  };

  componentWillUnMount = () => {
    let element = document.getElementById("elementInsideOfComponnet");
    element.removeEventListener(
      "websocketmessage",
      EventHelper.dispatchCustomEvent,
      false
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Component that will receive event from websocket</h1>

        <div id="elementInsideOfComponnet">Listening for global message</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Also added:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    GlobalFile.initSocket("id");
  }
```

to index.js (parent component) to initialize websocket connection. And to the render of the index.js:

```
<ComponentListeningForGlobalEvent />
<button onClick={GlobalFile.sendMessage}>Send websocket message</button>
```

Inserted Component that will receive event from websocket message, and button triggering webscket send message, so you can test (and see) that websocket message event is propagated all the way to the ComponentListeningForGlobalEvent.

I really hope this helps! :)

Comment: I don't have any HTML element.
I only have one global file : 

let jsWebSocket = null;

function initSocket(user_id) {
    
    jsWebSocket = new WebSocket("URL");
    jsWebSocket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
        jsWebSocket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log('message listener fired');
        });
    });
    
}
export { initSocket, sendMessage, disconnectSocket, jsWebSocket };

i want to fire an event into one of my component when message event fires from socket.

Comment: What does your Component looks like? Because if you have Component, your Component must have DOM element inside of render method?

Comment: I do understand you do not have HTML element inside of that global file, but Component you want to fire that event into has to have DOM elements (if we're talking about React Components).